# The pdf file size is huge created through iTextSharp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create PDF file, and I already added these code:

```
 .....................................................
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, filestream);
 writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_5);
 writer.CompressionLevel = PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
 writer.SetFullCompression();
 .....................................................
```

The file's size is 106M, and then I open from Acrobat and save, that file's size becomes only 5M.

**Update 1:**
the main part of my code looks like this:

```
for (var chart in charts.records)
{                  
   Stream kpistream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("KPIInfo." + "kpi.pdf");
   PdfReader kpireader = new PdfReader(kpistream);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(kpireader, ms);

   //some code here to insert a image to stamper      
   stamper.FormFlattening = true;
   AcroFields acrofileds = stamper.AcroFields;
   acrofileds.SetField("ID", chart.KPIId.Trim());
   // a couple of lines here to set the other acro fields
   stamper.Close();
   MergePages(document, writer, ms.ToArray());// this line is for adding this new created page to main pdf file
   ms.Close();
 }
```

**Update 2:**

```
public static void MergePages(Document document, PdfWriter writer, byte[] bytes)
{
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
  for (int index = 1; index <= reader.NumberOfPages; index++)
  {
     document.NewPage();

     PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, index);
     PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;
     content.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Open the file in Acrobat Pro and use "Audit Space Usage". Location depends on what version you have (Adobe sure likes to move commands around). My vsn, X Pro, has it as *option* in the Save As Optimized, Settings dialog.

Comment: I don't want to say this, but after struggling to use iTextSharp, I feel iTextSharp's functions are pretty powerful, but it is very hard to use it. Even feel it is very stupid.

Comment: It looks like you essentially use `PdfWriter` to merge multiple documents you create on the run. `PdfWriter` is **not** the right class for merging multiple PDFs, `PdfCopy` and (especially if you want the result to be small) `PdfSmartCopy`. `PdfWriter` is optimized for creating new documents using phrases, paragraphs, etc.

Comment: Because i have to use a template file, and then I have to use PdfStamper to create the page. From what I did, if I use PdfCopy I can't use template.

Comment: In that case please also show the `MergePages` code. I assume it can be improved.

Comment: In the most recent version of iText, Pdf(Smart)Copy can be used to merge templates. A method `addDocument()` was added. This method makes sure the form structure is preserved (although you may need to rename fields).

Answer (score 3):

Two things can affect PDF file size a lot: font and images, usually both are embedded inside a file and how the program handle them can have a big impact on the final file size. For example, if you have the same image that repeats 10 times in your PDF file, then one application might choose to keep 10 copies of the same image in the PDF file and another program might figure out that these 10 images are really the same and only keep one copy. The same problem can occur for font data.

Compression usually can affect the file size but unlikely varies between 5M and 106M. There is a case that this indeed can happen is that high resolution image obviously takes more space than low resolution image. So for example, if you have a 1200 dpi image in your PDF file, a tool can open it and reduce the resolution to 120 dpi thus greatly reduce the file size. while 1200 dpi is a very high resolution, 120 dpi is not bad at all and still can look fine on screen. This is what some so called "PDF compressor" does to make the file significantly smaller but no "visible" quality loss. In another word, they are not really compressing anything, they are just throwing out 90% of the image details. :)

To find out what's the problem, you may want to try other PDF library and see what comes out with those. Here is a decent one (but not free) that you can try:

http://www.essentialobjects.com/Products/EOPdf/Default.aspx

You can just use the trial version to see if it gives you the same result and that may help you to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks first. In my case, I don't have duplicated images, but I have 73 images all are 72dpi,800*500pixels

Comment: By default images are saved as JPEG in PDF, and JPEG does have a rather good compression ratio. So I am surprised that iTextSharp could create a file that big --- maybe because your original images are not JPEG. If that's the case, try to resave the image as JPEG would definitely help.